# How to clear an IME keyboard cache

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome

I'm trying to manage and replicate the input coming in from a keyboard using JavaScript.  This is trivial except when it comes to IME style keyboards that are the default for Android phones and Chrome OS tablets (or foreign language input).  While I've mostly been successful in replicating the input generated from composition events there is one major snag: the keyboard cache.

On Android and Chrome OS when a user is typing into a text area the keyboard remembers what was recently typed and will use it to prefill the composition when the user backspaces.  This is very detrimental to my objectives as it makes it hard for me to replicate the behavior without having to maintain my own version of the cache.  I've been able to clear the cache on Android by using `textarea.blur(); textarea.focus();` but this is not ideal and doesn't work on Chrome OS.  Does anyone know what can be done about the keyboard cache from a JavaScript perspective?

Comment: "I've been able to clear the cache on Android by using" -- I would not assume that this has your desired effect across all Android browsers and IME implementations.

Comment: I agree, its likely not a reliable method of clearing the cache.  The only other option I've seen mentioned anywhere is to make it a password field.